# How can I filter table and select rows which have parentid in id column

Tags: c#, linq, dataset

My table has tow columns id, parentid and I want to filter data to select rows which have parentid ( as there can be rows without parentid row).

```
id parentid
1  null
2   1
3   1
4   2
5   10
```

I want all the rows except 5, 10 as 10 is not there as a parent (no children unless parent is there).

I want rows with parentid as I am using the data for treeview.
I have tried couple of ways but not getting what I want.

```
var mycol = from t in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    where t.Field<int>("Id") == t.Fields<int>("ParentId");
    select t;
```

or

```
DataRow[] drs = ds.Tables[0].Select("ParentId in Id");
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want. Do you want to get all rows where ParentId is not NULL?

Comment: My question was edited by somebody and messed it up. I want rows with parentid == null (parent level 0 nodes) and rows with parentid (for which parentid exits in dataset). Based on the data shown in message, I don't want row 5, 10 and rest are all good. I can't include children unless parent is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what you want.

If you want rows where ParentId is not null, use one of the other answers.

If you want rows where Id is used as a ParentId somewhere in the dataset, use something like this:

```
var table = ds.Tables[0];

var parentIds = new HashSet<int>(
    from row in table.AsEnumerable()
    let parentId = row.Field<int?>("ParentId")
    where parentId != null
    select parentId.Value);

var rowsWhereIdIsAParentId =
    from row in table.AsEnumerable()
    let id = row.Field<int>("Id")
    where parentIds.Contains(id)
    select row;
```

Comment: My question was edited by somebody and messed it up. I want rows with parentid == null (parent level 0 nodes) and rows with parentid (for which parentid exits in dataset). Based on the data shown in message, I don't want row 5, 10 and rest are all good. I can't include children unless parent is there.

Comment: OK. I think between my answer and the other answer on here, your question has been answered.

Comment: I like the contains idea. There are 2 passes and I changed second part as data does include nulls.

Answer (score 0):

To get rows with `ParentId` not null, use

```
var rows = from r in ds.Tables[0].Rows.AsEnumerable()
    where !r.IsNull("ParentId")
    select r;
```

or

```
var rows = ds.Tables[0].Rows.AsEnumerable().Where(r => !r.IsNull("ParentId"));
```